# Reproduce Ajax request with cURL

Tags: ajax, symfony, curl

I'm trying to reproduce an Ajax request with cURL but it's always failing.
The server is not seing the sent data (my_data in the examples below) at all.

```
curl \
    --request POST \
    --header 'Content-type: application/json' \
    --header 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \
    --url 'http://example.org/ajax_call' \
    --data '{"my_data":"data_value"}'
```

I also tried:

```
 curl \
    --request POST \
    --header 'Content-type: application/json' \
    --header 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \
    --url 'http://example.org/ajax_call' \
    --data "my_data":"data_value"
```

And finally:

```
 curl \
    --request POST \
    --header 'Content-type: application/json' \
    --header 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \
    --url 'http://example.org/ajax_call' \
    -F "my_data=data_value"
```

The data is never caught by the server (Symfony in my case). I guess there is an issue with XMLHttpRequest formatting in cURL and I'm wondering if what I'm trying to do is even possible (meaning proper formatting of XMLHttpRequest object by cURL)

I crawled the net for hours and haven't found anything with data parameters so far.

Thanks for your help

**EDIT**

Solution found thanks to people in comment section was:

```
curl -v \
    --header 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \
    'http://example.org/ajax_call' \
    -d my_data=data_value
```

Comment: Is route set up to receive `POST` and cross origin from your domain?

Comment: What happens if you just type `curl 'http://example.org/ajax_call' -d my_data=data_value` and let `curl` try work it out with the server ?  If it works, then try again with `curl -v 'http://example.org/ajax_call' -d my_data=data_value` and then look at what values were set for Content-Type, Accept, and any other relevant headers.

Comment: The less options you give `curl`, the more it will try work it out for you.  For example, if you add the `-d data=value` argument, `curl` will automatically make it a `POST` request, without specifying `-X POST`.  Sometimes it helps with APIs to see what works, what doesn't, what settings matter, what settings are ignored.  etc.

Comment: Also @1252748 is right, again, check the response from `curl -v`, and you could additionally try `curl 'http://example.org/ajax_call?my_data=my_value'` to see if it responds to url query string params

Comment: How are you testing this symfony side? Does the POST work but just the data retreival doesn't? You should get some response, what is it?

Comment: Big thanks to you guys. I tried "curl -v 'http://example.org/ajax_call' -d my_data=data_value". It went a litle further and instead of missing data in the request like before I had an issuewith Reponse formatting because the XMLHttpRequest format was missing in the request header. So finally the proper command to make this work was: "curl -v --header 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' 'http://example.org/ajax_call' -d my_data=data_value"
I then tried again with the header related to Json and it failed. Some mysterious mismatch somewhere for some reasons...

Answer (score 0):

All your cURL requests are valid and can be processed. In Symfony app controller, you can access to sent JSON object by method [`getContent()`](http://api.symfony.com/3.2/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_getContent) of Request object:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/ajax_call", name="some_action")
 */
public function someAction(Request $request)
{
    if ('' !== $content = $request->getContent()) {
        $data = json_decode($content);
        // some action…
    }

    return new Response(null, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

In developer toolbar your request look like this:

[image]